# Obtaining Fourier Transform of a Function

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

I am getting two different answers for the Fourier transform of the same function $h(t) = {e}^{-2t} cos{\pi}t \space u(t-1).$

I don't find anything wrong in the two methods. What is the right answer and how?

#### Method 1 ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANFVh.jpg))

$$
\mathcal{F}[h(t)] 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2t} \cos\pi t \space u(t-1) e^{-j\omega t} dt
= \int_{1}^{\infty} {e}^{-2t} \cos{\pi}t \space e^{-j\omega t}  dt \\
= \int_{1}^{\infty} {e}^{-2t} \frac {(e^{-j \pi t}+e^{j \pi t})}{2} e^{-j\omega t} dt
= \frac{e^{-(2 + j \omega )+ j \pi}}{2(2 +j\omega - j\pi)} + \frac{e^{-(2 + j \omega )- j \pi}}{2(2 +j\omega + j\pi)}
$$

#### Method 2 ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM2Bc.jpg))

$$
h(t) 
= {e}^{-2t} \cos{\pi}t \space u(t-1)
= \frac{-1}{e^{2}}{e}^{-2(t-1)} \cos{\pi}(t-1) \space  u(t-1)
$$
Consider $ g(t) = {e}^{-2t} \cos{\pi}t \space u(t).$
$$
\mathcal{F}[g(t)] 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {e}^{-2t} \space \cos{\pi}t \space u(t) e^{-j\omega t} dt
= \int_{0}^{\infty} {e}^{-2t} \frac {(e^{-j \pi t}+e^{j \pi t})}{2} e^{-j\omega t} dt
= \frac{(2+j \omega)}{{(2+j \omega)}^{2} + {\pi}^{2}}
$$
Using time shift property, i.e.
$f (t − a)u(t − a) = e^{−j \omega a} F (\omega),$
$$
\mathcal{F}[h(t)] 
= \frac{-1}{e^{2}} e^{-j \omega} \frac{(2+j \omega)}{{(2+j \omega)}^{2} + 
{\pi}^{2}}
$$

Method 2 and Method 1 answers don't match after simplification. What is wrong?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format.

Comment: I have added it now  @Saad

Comment: When you write formulas in MathJax, put the whole formula inside `$...$` instead, e.g. write `$F[h(t)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ...$` instead of `F[h(t)] = $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$...`. Compare $F[h(t)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ...$ and F[h(t)] = $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$...

Comment: Okay! I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They **do** match:
$$
\frac{e^{-(2 + j \omega )+ j \pi}}{2(2 +j\omega - j\pi)} + \frac{e^{-(2 + j \omega )- j \pi}}{2(2 +j\omega + j\pi)} \\
= \frac{e^{-(2+j\omega)}}{2} \left( \frac{e^{j\pi}}{2+j\omega-j\pi} + \frac{e^{-j\pi}}{2+j\omega+j\pi} \right) \\
= \frac{e^{-(2+j\omega)}}{2} \frac{(2+j\omega+j\pi)e^{j\pi} + (2+j\omega-j\pi)e^{-j\pi}}{(2+j\omega-j\pi)(2+j\omega+j\pi)} \\
= \frac{e^{-(2+j\omega)}}{2} \frac{(2+j\omega)(e^{j\pi}+e^{-j\pi})+j\pi(e^{j\pi}-e^{-j\pi})}{(2+j\omega)^2+\pi^2} \\
= \frac{e^{-(2+j\omega)}}{2} \frac{(2+j\omega)2\cos\pi+j\pi\cdot2j\sin\pi}{(2+j\omega)^2+\pi^2} \\
= \frac{e^{-(2+j\omega)}}{2} \frac{(2+j\omega)2(-1)+j\pi\cdot 0}{(2+j\omega)^2+\pi^2} \\
= -\frac{(2+j\omega)e^{-(2+j\omega)}}{(2+j\omega)^2+\pi^2} \\
= -\frac{1}{e^2}e^{-j\omega}\frac{(2+j\omega)}{(2+j\omega)^2+\pi^2} \\
$$

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks!